# Initializing dynamic pointer to multidimensional array

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I am new to programming and am trying to implement A star search algorithm on C++. I am having segmentation fault:11 because of not initializing my pointer. I have tried it several different ways to no avail. 
I am still confused about the whole pointer and dynamic memory allocation concept.

Can anyone help me figure it out? Thank you.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;


    // Definition of the heuristic. The heuristic in this problem is the distance between
    // two coordinates
    double heuristic(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        double dx, dy;
        dx = x1 - x2;
        dy = y1 - y2;
        return sqrt(dx*dx - dy*dy);
        //return sqrt(pow((x1 - x2), 2) + pow((y1 - y2), 2));
    }

    // ----- A Star Search Algorithm (f = g + h)----
    double** a_star_search(double points[][2]) {
        int count = 1;
        double** points1 = NULL;
    //  points1[10][2];
        double x1 = points[0][0];
        double y1 = points[0][1];
        points1[count - 1][0] = x1;
        points1[count - 1][1] = y1;
        while (count <= 10) {
            double tempx1;
            double tempy1;
            double distance = 10000000;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if (points[i][0] != 0 && points[i][1] != 0) {
                    double distance2 = heuristic(x1, y1, points[i][0], points[i][1]);
                    if (distance2 < distance) {
                        tempx1 = points[i][0];
                        tempy1 = points[i][1];
                        distance = distance2;
                    }
                }
            }
            x1 = tempx1;
            y1 = tempy1;
            count++;
            points1[count - 1][0] = x1;
            points1[count - 1][1] = y1;
        }
        return points1;
    }

    int main() {
        double points[7][2];
        int counter = 0;
        ifstream infile("waypoints.txt");
        int a, b;
        while (infile >> a >> b)
        {
            points[counter][0] = a;
            points[counter][1] = b;
            counter++;
        }
        points[6][0] = points[0][0];
        points[6][1] = points[0][1];
        double** points1 = a_star_search(points);

        cout << "Initial Sequence: ";
        for (int i = 0;i < 7;i++) {
            cout << "(" <<points[i][0] << " , " << points[i][1] << "), ";
        }
        cout << "\n\nOptimized Sequence: ";
        for (int i = 0;i < 7;i++) {
            cout << "(" << points1[i][0] << " , " << points1[i][1] << "), ";
        }
        cout << "\n\nTotal Distance after A* search: ";
        double totaldistance = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i < 6;i++) {
            double dis = heuristic(points1[i][0], points1[i][1], points1[i + 1][0], points1[i + 1][1]);
            cout << dis << "+";
            totaldistance = totaldistance + dis;
        }
        cout<< "=" << totaldistance <<endl;
    }
```

Comment: You have tried what many ways? Allocating the dynamic array? You'll find how to do that thousands of places if you look, but don't bother. Give `std::vector` a try instead of the dynamic array. Save you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating memory dynamically for `double** points1` variable after setting it to `NULL` in your a_star_search function. As pointed out by @user4581301, use `std::vector`. This will simplify your code significantly and worth spending the time to learn STL containers.